# Test Javascript Function Wrapped in jQuery using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jasmine

I'm trying to test a JavaScript function nested within a jQuery function using Jasmine in a Rails application as follows:

jQuery (function () {
  var javascriptFunction = function () {
     ...functionality being tested...
  }
}

When I run the Jasmine test, I get the following error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: javascriptFunction"

If I place the JavaScript function outside of the jQuery function, I no longer receive that error; however, that JavaScript function needs to remain within the jQuery function in order for the rest of the application to work.

Is there a way to specify to Jasmine to look for the JavaScript function within the jQuery function?

Comment: I don't think there is. But in this case you can test the outcomes of what this function is doing. E.g. If it's setting up data then ensure it's setting it up correctly. In this case need to be testing the public interface

Comment: To do that, wouldn't I still need to call the outer jQuery method to set up the data?  I attempted to name the jQuery method and call it within the Jasmine test, but received the same error.

Comment: Can you put a concrete example into JSFiddle and paste the url here?

Comment: Here's the version without naming the jQuery function: http://jsfiddle.net/825oqhy3/

And here's the named version: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ad5kp3dv/

Comment: So in that example how would selectIsAcCheckbox be called?

Comment: Can you also elaborate a bit on "that JavaScript function needs to remain within the jQuery function in order for the rest of the application to work." please? Sorry I'm a bit slow today..

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated.  This is actually the current working version of the code http://jsfiddle.net/o306cbkk/1/.  In that implementation, the selectIsAcCheckbox is an anonymous function being called using $( document ).ready().  I named the function in order to test it, and have not yet modified the existing code to call the named function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so now I understand what you are trying to achieve.

There is no way to test what you have done as it is anonymous as you describe in your comments. The best way here is to add that code as a function somewhere. Could be on the window, or preferably on some other class somewhere. You can then test the outcome of calling your function at any point.

The JQuery ready function you are using is really just a way of starting your application. It says 'ok things are ready lets go'. In testing you are wanting that to happen and be repeatable so you can't rely on JQuery to do this.

```
//Current working version
function doTheThing(){
   if ($("#isac").length && $("#isac")[0].checked) {
    $(".nested-form-container").show();
    enableGraduatedCheckbox();
  } else {
    $(".nested-form-container").hide();
  }   
}

jQuery (function () {
  doTheThing();
}
```

Here is a similar discussion around the testability of what you are trying to do and the same suggestions. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204389/how-to-test-functions-or-the-code-inside-document-ready-using-jasmine

Comment: That's helpful.  Thanks!